# Slow performance when parsing log files

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I'm using C# to do processes over logs, I have very bad kinda performance overhead in this part of code. What should I do?

Though I even filter the logs. Still it takes over 2~3 minutes to process. My OS logs are set to 16 MB of size. But maybe on one server it be more or less.

```
List<LogParserDataEntity> dataEntities = new List<LogParserDataEntity>();
.
.
.
for (; !rs.atEnd(); rs.moveNext())
{
    dataEntities.Add(new LogParserDataEntity(
        rs.getRecord().getValue("eventlog").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("recordnumber").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("timegenerated").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("timewritten").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("eventid").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("eventtype").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("eventtypename").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("eventcategory").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("eventcategoryname").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("sourcename").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("strings").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("computername").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("sid").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("message").ToString(),
        rs.getRecord().getValue("data").ToString()
    ));
}
```

Comment: Do the rs have a length/count-property? In that case you can presize dataEntities to have the same length (as a minimum).

Comment: @Alxandr no... the component decide it's lenght

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what suggests that there are performance problems in this specific part of code? Did you use a profiler? If not, try one (dotTrace is free for 30 days, this should suffice) and see where's the problem.

Off the top of my head I'd suggest caching `rs.getRecord()` and replacing `dataEntities`, which looks like an `List<T>` with something like a `LinkedList<T>`.

Comment: ok, i'll catch... but what's the matter with replaceing list with LinkedList? aren't both of a same kind from the base?

BTW, i never used profiler on a code, ... i know here's slow becasue i put some trace but profiler? how it help?

Comment: sry, yesterday, while i tried to DL the dottrace, my network died from ISP side, ...
today morning a transformator in electricity line explode, so again ... :|

now... i did it.. Bue how can i test it over a windows service?

My app is windows service, and i launch it on other OS (win Ser 2003 OS) becasue i have no SQL in my machine, and since it take space on C drive, i just could install it on that Virtual machine...

Comment: i'm still wait to know how to use dottrace for a windows service, in another OS (after installation)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time will be in retrieving the records themselves
but a small improvement: getRecord only needs to be called once,

```
var record = rs.getRecord();
dataEntities.add(New LogParserDataEntry(
              record.getValue("eventlog").ToString,
              record.getValue(......
```

Comment: caching variable was awesome...

i think the component didn't store all record like me, and it tried to access the big log file and filter through it for each call...

a job that taked over 2~3 minutes... now is done within just some seconds...

Answer (score 1):

Cache the result of rs.getRecord():

```
for (; !rs.atEnd(); rs.moveNext())
            {
                var record = rs.getRecord();

                dataEntities.Add(new LogParserDataEntity(
                                     record.getValue("eventlog").ToString(),
                                     record.getValue("recordnumber").ToString(),
                                     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that caching `getRecord()` could help,
but if you find the process is still too slow you might want to consider using a tool like the free [Microsoft Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) - I haven't used it for a while but remember it as being very fast.

Comment: rs is an object filled with log parser utility :|

BTW, i'm wonder all application are so fast, like SQL too many processes, log parser it self, read too many records in less than a second, but i cant even fill my record set of data in 2~3 minutes :|

Answer (score 0):

A (probably tiny) further performance improvement may be obtained by writing/using a dataEntities contructor that receives the record, rather than all the stringized field-values, and process the value-retrieval in that constructor.

It is also more general: you don't need to recode much if the fields-to-use change any time in the future.

Comment: u say to use new dataEntity,...
that's what i did:
look after the add method:
`... new LogParserDataEntity( ...`